# Google Sheet : get cell informations and send all of it on click to an email address

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating [this wine order Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bTI2pN_Acssq5GgyoUthkGSLpYwe9Sm8OwGrd0B0Lng/edit#gid=0) and I'm trying to deal with js code to do some things. I've some basics but I'm trying for days...

I need to:

- Get all product information if it's filled (A14:E14 if D14 is filled)
- Get the personal informations that people have to fill about them (B52:B58)
- A submit button, onClick will send all these information to my email and clean the sheet to other client.

Comment: Why don't you use Google Forms instead of Google Sheets?

Comment: I could actually, so the process could be:
1. The person fill the sheet with his wine selection and quantity
2. He click on "ORDER"
3. Clicking on ORDER, he goes on the form
3. He fill the form
4. He submit the form
5. I receive by email the wine selected and quantity and the form information.
That is possible @FIL ?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Actually @FIL if I use a form, it have to be in addition to the sheet because the sheet is showing my client all wine informations and I have a formule who calculate the exact order cost according to your location.

Comment: Sheet should only be your price list it that case. Or you can set it as read-only, ask your clients to download it, fill what they want to get and send to you via your Form (you can set up file upload in the Form).

Comment: Ok I totally understand but my client work with 5/10 clients by month and he really liked the sheet. So
Is exist a way to onClick the Order button, sent the sheet in pdf to email and clear the sheet ?

Comment: Ok, so what if two clients will get on the sheet at the same time? This approach has many issues. You can post a new question about executing OnClick in Google Sheet but I warn you: it is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets are not the right tool to do this. You should move all your data to [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/forms/about/). There you can write a script to send you an email on each submit of the form.

Storing personal data in a publicly accessible Google Sheet is a very bad idea. This data should be properly secured.